# Bot replies to comments where he already replied at

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, reddit, praw

I wrote a bot with praw. I save the comment ids in a list named cache to avoid that the bot replies to comments he already replied at.
This is the method i use to save an id.

```
def saveCache(id):
    cache.append(id)

    data = open("cache.txt", "a")
    data.write(id)
    data.write('\n')
    data.close()
```

This also worked.

After a restart the bot should load all the ids from the file into the list:
cache = []

```
def loadCache():
    with open('cache.txt', 'r') as f:
        cache = f.readlines()
        print ("cache: ")
        for line in cache:
            print(line)
```

The output is correct.

But the bot replies to the comments where he already replied to.

Is my 'test' not correct?

```
 if id not in cache
     saveCache(id)
     comment.reply(message_to_reply_with)
```

Comment: Can you share more details about your test, that we all have a better overview.

Comment: What type is `id`? Because when you read it from file all entries will be a string, instead of `int` (or even bytes vs string)

Comment: The id is a string. It looks like this: d4p2rv0

Answer (score 1):

When you readback from cache.txt, the entries in the list also contains a trailing '\n'. So your match will fail.

try this to readlines without newlines.

```
with open('cache.txt', 'r') as f:
    cache = [ line.rstrip('\n') for line in f ]
```

Comment: or `cache = [ line for line in f ]`. I think this would be faster. :)

Comment: @erip I didnt knew it. btw, you mean cache = [ line.rstrip('\n') for line in f ] right?

Comment: you are right but still after I corrected my code he ignores the fact that he already replied to the comment